# Different behavior of delete_all and destroy_all

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a relation that I want to delete all the rows of

`Match.find(10237).inform_requests.near(Bar.first).via_email`

```
[5] pry(main)> Match.find(10237).inform_requests.near(Bar.first).via_email.class
=> InformRequest::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation
```

Trying to `destroy_all` generates very broken SQL..

```
[6] pry(main)> Match.find(10237).inform_requests.near(Bar.first).via_email.destroy_all
  Match Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `matches`.* FROM `matches` WHERE `matches`.`id` = 10237 LIMIT 1
  Bar Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `bars`.* FROM `bars`  ORDER BY `bars`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  InformRequest Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `inform_requests`.* FROM `inform_requests` WHERE `inform_requests`.`match_id` = 10237 AND (lat < 1.48591 and lat > 1.0859100000000002) AND (lng < 104.05 and lng > 103.64999999999999) AND (`inform_requests`.`email` IS NOT NULL)
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM `inform_requests` WHERE `inform_requests`.`` = NULL
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'inform_requests.' in 'where clause': DELETE FROM `inform_requests` WHERE `inform_requests`.`` = NULL
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'inform_requests.' in 'where clause': DELETE FROM `inform_requests` WHERE `inform_requests`.`` = NULL
```

`delete_all` works nicely

```
[8] pry(main)> Match.find(10237).inform_requests.near(Bar.first).via_email.delete_all
  Match Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `matches`.* FROM `matches` WHERE `matches`.`id` = 10237 LIMIT 1
  Bar Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `bars`.* FROM `bars`  ORDER BY `bars`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM `inform_requests` WHERE `inform_requests`.`match_id` = 10237 AND (lat < 1.48591 and lat > 1.0859100000000002) AND (lng < 104.05 and lng > 103.64999999999999) AND (`inform_requests`.`email` IS NOT NULL)
=> 1
```

The relation itself has 1 row in this case as the `delete_all` indicates.
Any idea why this difference? lat lng are not qualified cuz they are generated from a string sql condition based where. Not sure if that is the issue here..

Comment: Do you have `before_detroy` or `after_destroy` callback in the InformRequest model?

Comment: @H-man nope, no callbacks at all